# Where has StateMachine gone in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm working through the MSDN Windows Workflow Tutorial's and want to create a [StateMachine Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg983472.aspx).

The tutorial says:

> "Drag a StateMachine activity from the State Machine section of the
>   Toolbox and drop it onto the Drop activity here label on the workflow
>   design surface."

but this option does not exist in the toolbox of my Visual Studio 2012 Professional (all the others are there).

Where is it?

Comment: What's your project's target framework? StateMachine was only added on .NET 4.0.3

Comment: @Jota - That's the one! I upgraded to 4.5 and StateMachine is now available. If you want to make that an answer I can tick it. Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jota kindly pointed out - StateMachine was only added in .NET 4.0.3. When I upgraded the project to 4.5 (from 4.0) the StateMachine option appeared in my toolbox.

Thank you Jota.